# show forms for model who can have multiple instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a simple project which is about creating a resume by user. In resume, a user can have multiple experience, educational background and etc. That is why I have created the following table where experience, educational background, skills are foreignkey to the resume table.

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    applicant = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, help_text="Full Name")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Education(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, related_name='education')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, help_text="Name of an institution")
    course = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, help_text="Name of a course")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class Experience(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, related_name='experience')
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class Skill(models.Model):
    resume=models.ForeignKey(Resume, related_name="skills")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Name of the skill")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Skill'
        verbose_name_plural='Skills'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now for such situation, do I have to create a ResumeForm, EducationForm, ExperienceForm etc and create an Education, Experience and Skill formset or 
I have to do something else. I do not have clear idea on how to move forward now for developing form with such 
relation where Education, Skill can have multiple instance. Can anyone guide me, please?

Comment: I think you are looking for inline formsets: http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is unclear but following with your idea you have 2 options:

First you can have existing values in Education, Experience, Skill. Then in the view you have a checkbox to add education, experience, skill.

Second you can add education, experience, skill creating a modelForm for each one and then passing the resume, It is not necessary use formset here